# Trying to have a checkbox automatically check 2 other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, triggers

I'm very new to coding in java... So I apologize for the seemingly simple question.

However, In an Adobe PDF Form, I have a list of seven checkboxes, and when I select checkbox 2,3,or 4 I would like two other checkboxes to either be highlighted or selected.

So if Box B "r2w_att_B" is checked
then
"r2w_min_cond1" and "r2w_min_cond2" should both be checked.  and if the form filler decides to check those boxes before selecting B,C or D then nothing should change.  basically it is to ensure that you can't select B,C or D and "forget" to select the 2 minimum conditions.

and the same would be true for box C and D, so in theory the code should be the same with the exception of name of the initial box, I've used this line from another part of the form and it worked. so I could use that again.  [if (event.target.value == "Yes")]

I have no idea how to write this...  and the other code snippets I came across, I don't quite understand and cant make them work.
I did piece together a clip of functional code, that on "mouse up" a checkbox triggers a textbox to copy "value" to another text box.

I appreciate anyone and everyone's guidance as I start learning a Java

Comment: I believe you mean Javascript, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("ck1");
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("ck2");
var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("ck3");

checkbox1.addEventListener('change', function() {
 checkbox2.checked = this.checked;
 checkbox3.checked = this.checked;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1" name="ck1" value="Checkbox1">
  <label for="vehicle1"> Checkbox 1</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck2" name="ck2" value="Checkbox2">
  <label for="vehicle2"> Checkbox 2</label><br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck3" name="ck3" value="Checkbox3">
  <label for="vehicle3"> Checkbox 3</label><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ck4" name="ck4" value="Checkbox4">
  <label for="vehicle3"> Checkbox 4</label><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ReferenceError: document is not defined
1:Field:Mouse Up
This is in an Adobe form. not sure if that matters.

and I was unaware of that Java and Javascript are different, I appreciate the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (event.target.value!="Yes")
{getField("firstchkbox").value = "Yes";
getField("secondchkbox").value = "Yes";  }
```

This is ultimately how I got it to work in Adobe.
on mouse down, it executes a Javascript, and checks the two boxes.